# Walking main character by WSAD and rotation camera with mouse

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am not pretend on game design, but I want to do Interior design project with unity.
Now I am trying to create character, which walking in flat and looking around like in game.
I am using next script for this

```
public class MouseLooking : MonoBehaviour
{
CharacterController _characterController;
public float speed = 1;
public GameObject MainCamera; //аттач главной камеры для получения вектора направления движения
public GameObject Player; //Объект игрок
private float CurSppedV;




public float camSens = 0.25f; //How sensitive it with mouse
private Vector3 lastMouse = new Vector3(255, 255, 255); //kind of in the middle of the screen, rather than at the top (play)
// Start is called before the first frame update


void Start()
{
    
    _characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    CurSppedV = speed * Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    lastMouse = Input.mousePosition - lastMouse;
    lastMouse = new Vector3(-lastMouse.y * camSens, lastMouse.x * camSens, 0);
    lastMouse = new Vector3(transform.eulerAngles.x + lastMouse.x, transform.eulerAngles.y + lastMouse.y, 0);
    transform.eulerAngles = lastMouse;
    lastMouse = Input.mousePosition;
    //Mouse  camera angle done.  

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
    {
         Vector3 forward = transform.TransformDirection(0,0,1);
         
         _characterController.SimpleMove(forward * CurSppedV);
        
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
    {
         Vector3 back = transform.TransformDirection(0, 0, 1);
          _characterController.SimpleMove(back * CurSppedV);

    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
    {       
        Vector3 right = transform.TransformDirection(-1, 0,0);
        _characterController.SimpleMove(right * CurSppedV);
     
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
    {
        Vector3 left = transform.TransformDirection(1,0,0);
        _characterController.SimpleMove(left * CurSppedV); 
    }
   }
}
```

But I have little problem. When I press A and S character moves behind and right, when I press D and S character moves behind and left. When I press only A or D, character does not move anyway. What wrong?

Unity 2019.4.14f1 Personal

Comment: I tried, but it starts walking only forward and left if also D pressed and right if A pressed)))

Answer (score 2):

because if you only press A or D as single button your `CurSppedV` will be `0` due to

```
CurSppedV = speed * Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
```

For the other ones you should get the horizontal axis. Then I would rather assign the change only **once** in order to be able to clamp the magnitude.

Your if checks are pretty redundant since you basically already handle the according buttons by getting the axis value.

And note from [`transform.eulerAngles`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-eulerAngles.html)

> When you read the .eulerAngles property, Unity converts the Quaternion's internal representation of the rotation to Euler angles. Because, there is more than one way to represent any given rotation using Euler angles, the values you read back out may be quite different from the values you assigned. **This can cause confusion if you are trying to gradually increment the values to produce animation.**
>
> To avoid these kinds of problems, the recommended way to work with rotations is to avoid relying on consistent results when reading .eulerAngles particularly when attempting to gradually increment a rotation to produce animation. For better ways to achieve this, see the Quaternion * operator.

I would do it like this

```
void Update()
{
    var input = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxis("Vertical")).normalized;

    var movement = input * speed * Time.deltaTime;

    _characterController.SimpleMove(movement);  

    var mouseDelta = Input.mousePosition - lastMouse;
    var scaledDelta = new Vector2(-mouseDelta.y * camSens, mouseDelta.x * camSens);
    transform.rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(scaledDelta);
    lastMouse = Input.mousePosition; 
}
```

---

And just in general: instead of all these `transform.TransformDirection` why not simply nude the already built-in `transform.forward` and `transform.right`

for back use `-transform.forward` and for left use `-transform.right`.

Comment: I tried, but it starts walking only forward and left if also D pressed and right if A pressed)))

Comment: CurSppedV = speed * Input.GetAxis("Vertical"); ok, how fix it? Only Vertical or Horizontal  is posible. But with Horizontal nothing work at all

Comment: thanks for help. With your help I did script, witch works correctly

Answer (score -1):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MouseLooking : MonoBehaviour
{
CharacterController _characterController;
public float speed = 1;
public GameObject MainCamera;  
движения
public GameObject Player; 





public float camSens = 0.25f;
private Vector3 lastMouse = new Vector3(255, 255, 255);



void Start()
{
    
    _characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();

}


void Update()
{


    var input = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 
    Input.GetAxis("Vertical")).normalized;

    var movement = input * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    lastMouse = Input.mousePosition - lastMouse;
    lastMouse = new Vector3(-lastMouse.y * camSens, lastMouse.x * camSens, 0);
    lastMouse = new Vector3(transform.eulerAngles.x + lastMouse.x, 
    transform.eulerAngles.y + lastMouse.y, 0);
    transform.eulerAngles = lastMouse;
    lastMouse = Input.mousePosition;


    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
    {
         Vector3 forward = transform.TransformDirection(0,0,1);
         
         _characterController.SimpleMove(forward * speed);
        
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
    {
         Vector3 back = transform.TransformDirection(0, 0, -1);
          _characterController.SimpleMove(back * speed);

    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
    {       
        Vector3 right = transform.TransformDirection(-1, 0,0);
        _characterController.SimpleMove(right * speed);
     
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
    {
        Vector3 left = transform.TransformDirection(1,0,0);
        _characterController.SimpleMove(left * speed); 
    }

    
}
```

}